# Python find value in dictionary inside a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to return `True` using `values()` method for `480-888-0050`, which is in a list inside the `contacts` dictionary, but it doesn't seem to drill down inside the list for key `Mike`.

```
contacts = {
    'Ingemar': '480-555-7777', 
    'Mike': ['480-888-0050', '480-555-5555']
}

print('480-555-7777' in contacts.values())
print('480-888-0050' in contacts.values())

print(contacts.values())
```

Output:

```
True
False
dict_values(['480-555-7777', ['480-888-0050', '480-555-5555']])  <<< clearly sees the values
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What is generating `contacts`? If it's your code it might be easier to always use lists, ie `['480-555-7777']`, then both `'480-555-7777'  in itertools.chain.from_iterable(contacts.values())` and ``'480-888-0050'  in itertools.chain.from_iterable(contacts.values())`` will be `True`.

Answer (score 3):

You could write a function that tries to handle `str` differently than `list`

```
def contains(element, value):
    if isinstance(value, str):
        return element == value
    elif isinstance(value, list):
        return element in value
    return False
```

Then you can use this function in a generator expression with `any`

```
>>> any(contains('480-555-7777', value) for value in contacts.values())
True
>>> any(contains('480-888-0050', value) for value in contacts.values())
True
```

Comment: Very good answer! Just one question, why do you use any to check if the element is in the value when you figured out value is  a list? Wouldn't `return element in value` work as well?

Comment: @Eric Oh yeah good point. Guess I jumped ahead to thinking about using `any` afterwards, yeah `in` would be better in this case.

Comment: would you kindly give an example using "return element in value, instead of using any.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that some values are in keys and other in list. Using comprehension list for list value do the trick. If you want to test values everywhere in dict you can do like this:

```
values = contacts.values()
if '480-888-0050' in [x for v in values for x in v if type(v)==list] or '480-888-0050' in values:
    print("Value found")
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my previous answer:

'480-888-0050' is not a value the list

['480-555-7777', ['480-888-0050', '480-555-5555']]

its a value in the list that is in the list, if you want to check for all available values you want to merge all lists you can do this:

```
from itertools import chain

numbers = list(chain.from_iterable(
[l if isinstance(l, list) else [l] for l in contacts.values()]))

print('480-888-0050' in contacts.values())
```

Answer (score -1):

The list contains `['480-888-0050', '480-555-5555']`, and not `'480-888-0050'`
so search for the element, you need to search within the sublist.
Use:

```
print(any('480-888-0050' in sublist for sublist in contacts.values()))
```

Comment: This does not work for the case where the value is a single string, not a list of strings

Comment: This will break as long as the values are of mixed types.

Comment: @CoryKramer, could you elaborate on "not work where the value is a single string".

Comment: contacts = {'Ingemar': '480-555-7777', 'Mike B': ['480-888-0050']}

print(any('480-888-0050' in sublist for sublist in contacts.values()))
print(contacts)

seems to work as well?

Comment: @CoryKramer  It is working for that case too. I checked for print(any('480-555-7777' in sublist for sublist in contacts.values()))

Comment: @DeepSpace I tried it for mixed types, like the one given in the example, it is working for that case.